# Need to add elements in order by type to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am working with a giant list of data that I am parsing into xml.  For this question think in the order of many GB size and hundreds of millions of instances to work with.  I start with the initial list of data and parse it into a unique hashset that I can work with to eliminate duplicates and then I parse it into xml and save it.  I end up with something like this structure.

```
<class>...
</class>
<instance>...
</instance>
.
.
.
<instance>
</instance>
<class>
</class>
<instance>
</instance>
```

This is obviously not very easy to work with so I attempted to parse it into all the classes followed by all the instances.  I used a modification of the following code I found.

```
XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Root",
new XElement("Child1", 1),
new XElement("Child2", 2),
new XElement("Child3", 3),
new XElement("Child4", 4),
new XElement("Child5", 5)
);
XElement child1 = xmlTree.Element("Child1");
child1.AddAfterSelf(
new XElement("NewChild", 10)
);
Console.WriteLine(xmlTree);
```

This is basically what I wanted but since I did not have elements named like class1 class2 etc it was not quite perfect.  I ended up with something like this.

```
<class>
     <id>1</id>
     ....
</class>
<class>
     <id>42789945</id>
<class>
<class>
     <id>363445297</id>
</class>...
```

I would actually like the classes to stay in order and not reverse after the first as they are.  I am pretty sure that I could switch to addbefore and use the instance and accomplish what I want, but because of the first instance of that coming in a deeper loop I am afraid that could hurt performance.  So far this thing runs in the 1-2 minute range with my optimizations, but if I get deeper into the process it goes to hours if I am not careful.

My big question is am I missing a an easier way of getting after the last class, but before the first instance or will it hurt me to add it before the instance?

Thanks
Jimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a test while waiting for an answer.  I will leave this just in case anyone else comes across this issue because I have not found a similar question.  When you use AddBeforeSelf it stops at the first iteration even if there are millions afterwards so switching to AddBeforeSelf did not add any time to my execution so I will stick with that unless someone just says the entire approach was wrong.

Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Root", new XElement[] {
                new XElement("Child1", 1),
                new XElement("Child2", 2),
                new XElement("Child3", 3),
                new XElement("Child4", 4),
                new XElement("Child5", 5)
            });​
```